# Codeigniter Full Calendar Integration

Tags: codeigniter, fullcalendar

I used full calendar in my CodeIgniter project to manage events. All other parts of the project are working properly. But the calendar output is look like this :

[image: Calendar Events]

The dates are collapsed in the output. Relevant JavaScript for calendar as follows :

```
<Script>
    $(document).on('click', '.month_select', function() {
        var month = $(this).data('month');
        var moment = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
        var currentMonth = moment.format('YYYY') + '-' + month + '-' + 10;
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', currentMonth);
    });
    $(function() {
        $('#viewed,#new,#issued,#recieved,#request,#return, #requestProofs').on('ifChanged', function(event) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
        });
        
        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate(),
            m = date.getMonth(),
            y = date.getFullYear();
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            aspectRatio: 1.7,
            firstDay: 1,
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
            },
            allDay: true,
            buttonText: {
                today: 'today',
                month: 'month',
                week: 'week',
                day: 'day'
            },
           
            events: {
                url: "<?= site_url('document/getImprestDocuments') ?>",
                data: function() { 
                    return {
                        viewed: $('#viewed').is(':checked'),
                        new: $('#new').is(':checked'),
                        issued: $('#issued').is(':checked'),
                        recieved: $('#recieved').is(':checked'),
                        request: $('#request').is(':checked'),
                        requestProofs: $('#requestProofs').is(':checked'),
                        return: $('#return').is(':checked'),
                    };

                },
                error: function() {
                    $('#script-warning').show();
                }
            },
            eventClick: function(event) {
                if (event.url) {
                    window.open(event.url);
                    event.color = event.default_color;
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);                    
                    return false;
                }
            },
            eventRender: function(event, element) {               
            },
            loading: function(bool) {
                if (bool) {
                    $(this).block({
                        message: '<div class="loading-message"><h3 style="margin: 5px;"><img style="width:35px;" src="<?= base_url() ?>public/dist/img/ring-alt.gif" >&nbsp;&nbsp;Processing...</h3></div>',
                        cenrerY: true,
                        css: {
                            border: '3px solid rgb(221, 75, 57)'
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    $(this).unblock();
                }
            }
        });

    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $("#request_imprest").DataTable({
            "order": [
                [1, "desc"]
            ],
            columnDefs: [{
                sortable: false,
                "class": "index",
                targets: 0
            }]
        })
        table.on('order.dt search.dt', function() {
            table.column(0, {
                search: 'applied',
                order: 'applied',
            }).nodes().each(function(cell, i) {
                cell.innerHTML = i + 1;
            });
        }).draw();
    })
</script>
```

`url: "<?= site_url('document/getImprestDocuments') ?>"` is also working fine. What may be going wrong ? Can anyone help ?

Comment: Have you checked your browser console log for reports?

Comment: @ Samuel Asor. Yes. I has no error

Comment: I'd say you probably forgot to load the relevant CSS file for fullCalendar